# AttributeError: 'CrawlerRunner' object has no attribute 'spiders'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm facing a bit of problem; I've worked a scrapy project long time ago and I wanted to relaunch it. I have differents spiders and I regrouped them in one main script that launch them all. Fun fact it was working at that time but now I have an Attribute error (AttributeError: 'CrawlerRunner' object has no attribute 'spiders'). Here is my code :

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor
from LesInfosDuJour.pipelines import LesinfosdujourPipeline

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

for spider_name in runner.spiders.list():
    runner.crawl(spider_name)

d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
obj = LesinfosdujourPipeline()
obj.empty_procedure()
obj.duplicate_procedure()
```

I'm launching it with python (python news-scrap.py)

setting.py

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['LesInfosDuJour.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'LesInfosDuJour.spiders'
```

Project directory :
Scrap/LesInfosDuJour/spiders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, scrapy on the latest update removed the CrawlerRunner.spiders method and replaced it with CrawlerRunner.spider_loader

Here is the changements I made :

```
configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
spiders_list = list(runner.spider_loader.list())

for spider_name in spiders_list:
    runner.crawl(spider_name)

d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```